# How do I catch exception from sed when trying to read a non-existent file and write a handler for it?

Tags: scripts, sed

I am fetching specific value from a text file using sed into a variable.
If the file does not exist, an error will be printed:

> sed: can't read filepath: No such file or directory

How can I catch this error and display my own message and do my logic?

```
export RESULT=`sed '' ${FILE_PATH} | grep ${VAR_NAME}  | cut -d "=" -f2-`
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` returns non-zero exit code when it fails. So you need to  test `$?` after `sed` (but before the pipes, else their possibly zero exit codes may "overwrite" `sed`'s)